# How to calculate sum of these vectors?

Tags: geometry, vectors

> **Question**: Find the vector sum:
> $$ \vec{AB} + \vec{CE} - \vec{CB} - \vec{KE} + \vec{MP} - \vec{KP}$$

I have approached the problem like this:

$$\vec{AB} + \vec{BC} + \vec{CE} - \vec{KE} + \vec{MP} - \vec{KP} \\
  = \vec{AC} + \vec{CE} + \vec{EK} + \vec{MP} - \vec{KP} \\
  = \vec{AE} + \vec{EK} + \vec{MP} - \vec{KP} \\
  = \vec{AK} + \vec{MP} - \vec{KP} \\
  = \vec{AK} + \vec{MP} + \vec{PK}\\
  = \vec{AK} + \vec{MK}$$

How do I simplify $\vec{AK} + \vec{MK}$?

Comment: without any extra information, this is as far as you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N$ is a midpoint of a segment $AM$, then $$ \vec{AK} + \vec{MK} = 2\vec{NK}$$

Comment: Yeah, I know it but I can't use `N` midpoint because the question is a part of a quiz (

Comment: Then your work is done, you cannot simplyfy it more unless there are information you have not given us.

Comment: Thanks a lot ;)